# Playlist and piano roll zoom in horizontally in FL Studio

Tags: fl-studio

I didn't use FL Studio since version 8. There are many things which have changed. I cannot figure out how to zoom in or zoom out horizontally in the playlist or piano roll.

Comment: I'm sure this may not want to what you want to hear, but isn't that what the manual is supposed to be for?

Comment: probably, but since this is site for answering questions about audio and video, i dont need to bother to read manual..

Comment: @1ucid As a courtesy to those answering questions, it is generally a good idea to read the manual and search around a bit before asking.  Please read the '[how to ask](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)' help page for more information.  If after doing some basic research you still cannot find the answer please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, @FriendOfGeorge for clarifying. Also thanks for converting my non-answer to a comment. I didn't know exactly how this stuff is handled here.

Answer (score 3):

In the playlist on the top right corner you have a square where you can set the zoom of the playlist.

If you point your cursor on the scrollbar, and use your mousewheel you can also adjust the zoom.

Pretty handy if you are used to it